# How to add NSTextField over SKScene?

Tags: objective-c, macos, sprite-kit

I am creating a game using Sprite Kit, want to add a text field over scene. Here is the code:

```
@interface MKMainMenuScene ()

//...
@property (nonatomic) NSTextField *field;

@end

@implementation MKMainMenuScene

- (void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view
{
    [super didMoveToView:view];

    [self.view addSubview:_field];
}

- (id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size
{
    if (self == [super initWithSize:size])
    {
       //...
       _field = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:
       NSMakeRect(self.frame.size.width / 2, self.frame.size.height / 2 + 20,
                  100, 40)];
       [_field setBackgroundColor:[NSColor whiteColor]];
       [_field setStringValue:@"Enter smth"];
    }

    return self;
}
```

But text field doesn't appear, it is under the scene. Does someone know what is the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: Does your code enter the `if` test? Shouldn't you do "=" instead?

Comment: @Larme, yes, all code inside "if" block is performed. Changing to "=" does not help.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did anyone figure this one out?

Answer (score 1):

Got it working.

Must set necessary views as Layer-Backed Views. Tried doing this in the Nib, didn't work for me. So I did it in code.

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    /* Insert Label. FOR TESTING, may remove */
    NSTextField *label = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(50, 50, 300, 300)];
    [label setStringValue:@"Hello All"];
    [label setTextColor:[NSColor whiteColor]];
    [label setBackgroundColor:[NSColor redColor]];
    [label setFont:[NSFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:20]];
    [[self.window contentView] addSubview:label];

    /* SET LAYER BACK VIEW 
     *  This is the one line code to make it work. 
     */
    [self.window.contentView setWantsLayer:YES];
}
```

**UPDATE:**

The above code will cause a freeze or a problem on either a `SCNView` or `SKView`. To fix this, don't set the UI as a subview, but as a sibling to `SKView`. And then set the UI as Layer-Backed by `setWantsLayer`.

```
Window
   -> Content NSView
      -> SKView/SCNView
      -> NSTextField  <-- Layer-Backed
```

Code:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    /* Insert Label. FOR TESTING, may remove */
    NSTextField *label = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(50, 50, 300, 300)];
    // . . . .
    [[self.window contentView] addSubview:label];


    /* UPDATE */
    [label setWantsLayer:YES];
}
```

Hope this helps someone else who's following my steps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
- (void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view
{
    [super didMoveToView:view];
    [view addSubview:_field];
}
```

Comment: The same result. There are scene's nodes over the text field. Also tried method `[view addSubview:_field
          positioned:NSWindowAbove relativeTo:view]`;

Comment: @user3553778, can you provide a screenshot? This definitely should work if there is no other view on skView.

Comment: I have created simple example of this problem with Apple's sample: [link](https://github.com/Moonko/Example). Can not do screenshot because the field appears on the screen just for a moment and then it is covered by scene.

Comment: @user3553778, maybe you should use compound NSView which will contain SKView and NSTextField as its subviews?

Comment: I did this. It didn't work. But for some reason in iOS, adding subviews to `SKView` works. Not for `SKView` that inherence `NSView`